# Add a listener to a CompilationUnitEditor Eclipse PDE

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I am developing an Eclipse RPC application and I have an editor (`MainEditor`) that contains two pages. The first page (***Properties***) displays the data of the model using some text fields and the second page (***Source***) is an editor that is instantiated from a class (`SourceCodeEditor`) that inherits the `CompilationUnitEditor` class and displays the source code that contains some annotations and some code.The annotations' values should correspond to the data in the model (the data is stored in variables in the model) .The new class (`SourceCodeEditor`) does nothing special it only override two super functions and executes the super implementation  like so :

```
@Override
public void doSave(IProgressMonitor progressMonitor) {  
        super.doSave(progressMonitor);
    }

@Override
public void doSaveAs() {
        super.doSaveAs();
    }
```

So I would like to add a listener to the instance of the `SourceCodeEditor` variable that updates the values of the annotations to correspond to the data in the model every time this editor/page is opened. The reason for that is that when I change a text field in the "Properties" page and open the "Source" page without saving the text displays the values before the change not after. If there is a better way to bind the values of the annotations in the source code and the variables of the model,please let me know.

Comment: Note `CompilationUnitEditor` is an internal class and as such should not be extended. The class may change significantly between Eclipse releases breaking your code.

Comment: I am open to suggestions , is there a better way to do this?